# How can I check if an array value in an array of floats is null/does not contain a value?

Tags: java, arrays, floating-point

I need to go through an array of 2D float values, checking if the array has a value or is null. I am confused on how I can check if the array value is null, since it's an array of floats?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: I'm using data objects so my array is accessed using:   data.floatArray  . And I'm trying to use an if statement to say:     if (data.floatArray[i][j] != null) { }  but it gives me an error, saying that the operator != is undefined for the types float, null

Comment: I'm using java.

Comment: Ok, so that means your data type is a `float[][]`.  The only thing that can be null is the entire array itself or one (or more) of the inner `float[]`s.

Comment: Okay thanks that actually solved my issue

Comment: @punchkey To be precise `null` comparison works with `object`s only and your `array` seems to be of primitive `float`.